# Accessing crateDB via Apache Drill

Tags: postgresql, apache, apache-drill, cratedb

I need to access data in my crate database via Apache Drill. 
Far as i have read, crate has a [PostgreSQL interface](https://crate.io/docs/clients/jdbc/), but that is not compatible with the [PostgreSQL interface](https://drill.apache.org/docs/rdbms-storage-plugin/) exposed by drill.
There isn't much information on this available on the internet.
One way to go about it is implementing a custom storage plugin. But did not find helpful information about that either. i went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557388/how-to-write-custom-storage-plugin-for-apache-drill), but not to much avail. Any insights, references, links, information is appreciated.

Another way i tried connecting to crate via apache drill was using the storage configuration:

> { 
>  type: "jdbc", 
>    enabled: true, 
>    driver:
>   "io.crate.client.jdbc.CrateDriver",  
>   url:"jdbc:crate://localhost:5432/" 
>  }

and jars:
crate-jdbc-1.9.1.jar and crate-jdbc-standalone-2.2.0.jar

This did not work for me either.

Comment: i'd be happy to explore this deeper and help debugging. did you try with our JDBC driver? what's the error message? i'm `jodok.crate` on the CrateDB community slack channel https://crate.io/docs/support/slackin/

Comment: Hey jodok, thank you for replying. Apache drill accepts a PostgreSQL storage plugin in the following format: {
  type: "jdbc",
  enabled: true,
  driver: "org.postgresql.Driver",
  url:"jdbc:postgresql://1.2.3.4/mydatabase",
  username:"user",
  password:"password"
} where as, for crate, we need to provide the connection URL like: jdbc:crate://localhost:5432/, Apache drill does not recognise this and is unable to create the storage plugin. The only error fired by Apache Drill is : Please retry: error (unable to create/ update storage), No further information is available in the logs too

Comment: the first syntax should work as well: https://crate.io/docs/clients/jdbc/#jdbc-url-format can you try?

Comment: Please check my post edit, it did not work for me. I had started Apache drill and crate before going forward with those steps. Please let me know if something is amiss.

Answer (score 0):

I could successfully connect to crate via Apache Drill using the following configuration: 
 

1. Storage configuration to connect to crate via Apache Drill (embedded mode):

> {
>     "type": "jdbc",
>     "driver": "io.crate.client.jdbc.CrateDriver",
>     "url": "jdbc:crate://localhost:5432/",
>     "username": "crate",
>     "password": null,
>     "enabled": true
>   }

2. Use the jar crate-jdbc-standalone-2.2.0. 
    Add it in drill-installation-dir/jars/3rdparty 
   In drill-installation-dir/conf/drill-override.conf add line

   > drill.exec.sys.store.provider.local.path = "crate-jdbc-standalone-2.2.0.jar"

Query Sample:

> select * from cratestorageplugin.doc.test

where: 
 cratestorageplugin: storage plugin created for crate

 doc: schema name

 test: table name

> Kudos and big big thanks to crate team for all their help and prompt
>   support!

Note: This method can prove useful, if your tables do not have dynamic data type. We can only query tables with simple data types with this connection.